# How to access BlueStacks' localhost from Windows?

Tags: android, networking, android-emulator, bluestacks

After some research I managed to access Windows' localhost from Bluestacks. If I open Google Chrome in BlueStacks and type 10.0.2.2:/... I can access Windows' localhost.

How do I do this the other way around? Is there a way to connect to Bluestacks' localhost from Windows?

Answer (score -2):

Check your IP within your network with `ipconfig` (type `ipconfig` in console)

There should be something like this: (here: VirtualBox)

```
Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network:

        Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
        Autoconfiguration IP Address. . . : 169.254.106.123
        Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
        Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

`169.254.106.123` is your address you are looking for.

`ping` it to see that it works, run a server and you will be able to connect to it.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I know localhost is at 127.0.0.1. From what I understand Bluestacks operates inside a VM and has it's own network. Android emulators like this one can access the host's localhost through 10.0.2.2, but what I'm looking for is a way to access the emulator's network from the host.

Comment: Write it in question then.